# Missing Text on application but visible on simulation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am very new at programming java so forgive my ignorance.

I have started making my first app on Android studio which controls the colours on an RGB table that I made. I have imported a colour picker library to use in the app. In the simulation the app works OK. But when I use the app on my phone (Galaxy note 8 with Android Version 9 & One UI version 1.0) there is some text that is not visible. And I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated. I added and images showing which text is missing on the phone.

[Simulation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuxeG.jpg)

[Physical App on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwDnj.jpg)

This is the library I am using: https://github.com/duanhong169/ColorPicker

Thank you

Weskus

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the device?

Comment: Do you use night mode? See https://github.com/duanhong169/ColorPicker/issues/13. Is this problem reproduced on another phone?

Comment: I added an image on the actual app running on my phone

Comment: @CoolMind I think that might be the problem. I've search for ages not sure why I did not see this, thanks so much for the help I do appreciate it.

Comment: @Weskus, good luck!